# How to log in automatically using Device after registration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mobile-fu

In my rails application I am using `devise` gem for to manage users. I am using `mobile_fu` gem for to separate users coming from different users.

What I want to achieve here is:

1. If a user opens my site from a mobile device I will extract its `MSISDN` number reading header it is already done
2. If that `MSISDN` number falls in a particular series then I want to automatic login that user to my website so that he will not have to fill the sign_in form.

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to:

1) Register the user into the website for devise.
2) Login the user.

For option 1, you can do something like:

```
user = User.find_by_msisdn(params[:msisdn])
if user.nil?
  user = User.create(field_1: value1, field_2: value2)    
end

sign_in(user)

redirect_to after_sign_in_path(user)
```

The things to have in mind, the first line tries to find for the user, on the second line, if it cannot find the user, it creates the user right away, then it sign_in the user, and finally redirect the user to where he should go after the login.

Comment: I tried this, but when redirected to a different page the user isn't logged in anymore.  Right after sign_in(user) there is data in current_user and user_signed_in? returns true.  However, user_signed_in? returns false when directed to different pages on the site.  Any ideas?

Comment: user_session is blank.  I'm assuming that has something to do with that.  Any suggestions on how to set the user session?

Comment: `after_sign_in_path` is renamed to `after_sign_in_path_for`.