# Devise and STI, created user not being logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, sti

can someone tell me why my newly created user is not automatically logged in please?
(Rails 3.2.2, Devise 3.2.1)

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

admin.rb

```
class Admin < User
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(Admin.new, :as => :admin, :url => registration_path(:admin)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :welcome
  resources :dashboard

  devise_for :users, :skip => :registrations
  devise_for :admins, :skip => :sessions

  devise_for :users, :controller => {:sessions  => 'sessions'}, :skip => [:sessions] do
      delete '/logout', :to => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
      get '/login', :to => 'sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
      post '/login', :to => 'sessions#create', :as => :user_session
  end

  authenticated :user do
    root :to => "dashboard#index"
  end

  root :to => 'welcome#index'
```

Comment: what do you mean "not automatically logged in"? were you able to sign up?

Comment: The user was signed up, but not signed in.

Comment: Did you define custom registrations controller?

Answer (score 1):

It all changed with Devise 3.1. From their [blog post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/):

> Devise 3.1 no longer signs the user automatically in after confirmation

You could of course do it manually with `sign_in(user)`. Look [Rails Devise gem automatic login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774852/rails-devise-gem-automatic-login).

Comment: I am not using the "comfirmable" module

Answer (score 0):

Devise 3.1 no longer signs in the user automatically in after a registration for security purposes => http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/

You can temporarily bring the old behavior back after upgrading by setting the following in your config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.allow_insecure_sign_in_after_confirmation = true
```

This option will be available only temporarily to aid migration.